# Objective C datatype for parse tree?

Tags: objective-c, types, tree

What is a good datatype for building data trees in objective C? I want to store a tree of strings, each node having mutiple children etc..

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [NSTreeNode](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSTreeNode_class/Introduction/Introduction.html) and [NSTreeController](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTreeController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)